# How to use dynamic parameter(ID) to axios api call in this example

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

How to use dynamic parameter ID to `axios api` in this example

```
this.$axios.post('/api/roles/{role_id}/permissions/{permission_id}')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as follows:

```
this.$axios.post(`/api/roles/${role_id}/permissions/${permission_id}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you use ` for your string templating?

```js
const role_id = "something"
const permission_id = "something"
this.$axios.post(`/api/roles/${role_id}/permissions/${permission_id}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url='/api/roles/'+ role_id+'/permissions/'+permission_id;
axios.post(url)
```